# Sorting only current page md-data-table

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm trying for hours to figure out why is my [md-data-table](https://github.com/daniel-nagy/md-data-table) **only sorting the current page**.
The **same thing is happening on the search filter.**
Can someone say why is it doing this and how can i fix it?

```
<input ng-model="searchInterview">

<md-table-container>
    <table md-table="" md-progress="promise" ng-model="selected">
        <thead md-head md-order="sort.order">
            <tr md-row>
                <th md-column md-order-by="dataapplicazione"><span>Data app</span></th>
                <th md-column md-order-by="nomecognome"><span>Nome e cognome</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody md-body>                
            <tr md-row ng-repeat="item in main.interviewsList |  limitTo: sort.limit : (sort.page -1) * sort.limit  | orderBy:sort.order | filter:searchInterview ">
                <td md-cell>{{ item.dataapplicazione | date}}</td>
                <td md-cell>{{ item.nomecognome }}</td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</md-table-container>
<md-table-pagination md-limit="sort.limit" md-limit-options="limitOptions" md-page="sort.page" md-total="{{main.interviewsList.length}}" md-on-paginate="promiseInterviews" md-page-select></md-table-pagination>
```

**Sorting Desc**
[image: 1]
**Sorting Asc**
[image: 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe change the order of the filters?

Also; this is in the documentationof mg-data-table:

> My Pagination Isn't Working?!
>
> Make sure you pass md-page, md-limit, and md-total to the directive and that they are finite numbers.
> Pages are not zero indexed. The directive will assume pages start at one. If your query language expects pages to be zero indexed then just subtract one before making the query.

Comment: Jesus crist that was it. I changed the order like this `| orderBy | filter |  limitTo` and it works. I wanna brake something for this wasted time! Thanks by the way ^_^